# Sitecore Forms submit action saving contact into Experience profile

Tags: sitecore-forms, experience-profile

Using Sitecore forms for Contact Us form submissions.

I used Sent Email Campaign Message and Redirect To Page submit actions, but contacts are getting saved into Experience profile with the email from To field. Save Data submit action is not used.

Is creating contacts in Experience Profile the default behavior for Sen Email form action?

Is there anyway to stop saving these data into Experience Profile?

Is there any PowerShell script or any way to delete existing Experience Profile data?

Version: Sitecore 9.1.1

Comment: Welcome to sitecore stack exchange. Please make sure to not post several questions into one as Alina already responded to some of your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to delete all Experience Editor data you should follow the instructions from the sitecore documentation
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/91/sitecore-experience-platform/en/rebuild-the-reporting-database.html and also make sure to rebuild the index as rebuilding the reporting database is not covering this.

In order to delete contacts you can take a look at the sitecore documentation https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/93/sitecore-experience-platform/en/deleting-contacts-and-interactions-from-the-xdb.html, however you should take into consideration the points highlighted in [How to delete a Contact programmatically in xDB](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/how-to-delete-a-contact-programmatically-in-xdb)

Comment: Want to delete contacts under Experience profile not Experience editor data.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at Sitecore code, creating a contact (that shows up in Experienced Profile) is default behavior of Sitecore Form action: Send Email Campaign Message.
Save Data action does not create contacts it just saves data that is submitted to the form, so is accessible at a later time for download.
Identify Contact action is the one that explicitly creates a Sitecore Contact (that shows up in Experience Profile)
If you are interested in a clean Send Email action you can look for [Sitecore Forms](https://github.com/bartverdonck/Sitecore-Forms-Extensions) Extensions